# How can I add indentation to a Word paragraph using the 'officer' package in R?

Tags: r, officer

I am writing R code to automate several reports. The results have to be Word documents, so I am using the 'officer' package. Figure and table titles are added as seperate paragraphs using the ftext() function. This is done so that figure and table titles are identical (graph titles from ggplot deviated from the style of the text generated by the officer package).

A few titles are longer than one page and cover multiple lines. Those titles I would like to be indented so that the second line aligns with the start of the title (minus the "Figure x." part).

I want all lines after the first to be indented like so:

```
Figure 1. First line of the title is followed by
          indented lines on consecutive lines.
```

In Word this can be done using: Paragraph -> Idents and Spacing -> Indentation -> "Hanging"

Is there any way a similar result can be achieved using R/the officer package?

Comment: One option would be to add a style with the desired indentation to your docx template which you could then apply using `officer`.